# Permutation or Combination?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

There are 9 people such as P1,P2,...,P9 who have to stand in a line but P1 and P2 will each get angry if they are not in the first 3 or last 3 spots in line. How many ways can these people line up such that both P1 and P2 will not get angry?

I am confused as to what formula do I have to use to get the answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to include what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. Or I'm afraid your question might be downvoted and closed.

Comment: For counting problems, the formulas are not helpful as such. You need to break into cases etc. and then do the counting.

Comment: Edit in what you have tried so far so we know your exact difficulty. As general guidance, use permutations where order matters, and combinations where it doesn't.

Comment: What is the probability that, at random, neither P1 or P2 are in the middle 3 slots?  You can construe the problem to be a probability problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, place $P1$ and $P2$ in adequate spots, there are $$6\cdot 5=30$$ ways to do so.

After this initial election, there are $7$ free spots where we can freely arrange the remaining people. There are $$7!=5040$$ ways to do so.

We conclude there are $30\cdot 5040=151200$ ways that they can line up without $P1$ or $P2$ getting angry